# Open spelling correction dialog by keyboard shortcut instead of right click

Tags: gnome, spell-checking

Say I go into a browser (chrome) or a chat window (empathy) and type "calandar", an obvious misspelling of the word calendar. The word is underlined with red squiggles and I want to auto correct this word. I could right click on the misspelled word and pick the correction, but using the mouse is inefficient.

How could I invoke the spell correction dialog with a keyboard shortcut and have it work across all apps?

Answer (score 4):

Probably the simplest way is to use your <kbd>Menu</kbd> button on your keyboard

i.e.  cursor backwards to the *squiggle* and press <kbd>Menu</kbd>.  Then select the suggested correction.

If you don't have a *Menu* key, map a keyboard shortcut (search in dash for *Keyboard Shortcut*) to a key combination (e.g. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) to the command

```
xdotool keydown Menu
```

N.B. install the package `xdotool` if you haven't already got it installed

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

Comment: the shift + f10 menu doesn't seem to account for the word, only the whole textarea's set of options

Comment: I presume that means you dont have a Menu key... how about my amended answer?

Comment: after running that `xdotool keydown Menu`, it looks like that's opening the same menu that shift+f10 does.. Thanks for trying to help out.

Comment: by the way i'm testing this in an empathy chat window

Comment: on 11.04, gnome2

Answer (score 2):

Mine works when I just hit <kbd>F10</kbd>, forget about the shift.  The <kbd>F10</kbd> button even says "spell" on it, so it works all by itself.